# How to write Typescript declaration file for external javascript node module

Tags: angular, typescript, requirejs, systemjs, mercadopago

I have an Angular 6 application, which needs to use external JS library from  npm. I found this tutorial(
https://dev.to/suhas_chatekar/converting-a-javascript-project-to-typescript-one-file-at-a-time), but there author *export functions instead of require another file*

**Can you help me please to write a part, where I have export all module instead of a function?**

I want to use it **inside Component** like this

```
import {} from 'node_modules/custom_module';
declare let sdk: any;
```

Provider doesnt have a d.ts. declarion file, and Im trying to improvise. I created **an index.d.ts file** which includes following

```
declare module "sdk" {
    export function gets(): any;
}
```

**index.js** where initial looks like this

```
let gets = () => {
    var r = require('./lib/module.js');
    return r;
  }

  module.exports = {
    gets     : gets
  }
```

**module.js** looks like this

```
var sdk;
sdk = module.exports = function () {
  var options = {
...
```

I use this node module

> https://github.com/mercadopago/dx-nodejs